# How can I perform the equivalent of Expect's "interact" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ssh, interactive

I want to spawn an SSH session, respond to a password prompt to login, and then interact with the remote system. This is easy to do with Expect, but I'm finding it challenging to do this in Ruby.

In Expect, I'd simply do something like:

```expect
log_user 0
spawn ssh user@host
expect "assword" { send "my_password\r" }
interact
```

However, the Ruby [IO#expect](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/expect/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-expect) method won't provide the interactivity that I'm after. I'm also reading through the [Net::SSH documentation](https://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/Net/SSH.html), but haven't found an obvious way to make the session interactive after successfully logging in.

Once the connection is successfully opened, what is needed to make the TTY/PTY on the remote host interactive?

Comment: I'm really hoping this can get an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, install the `net-ssh` gem in your command prompt.

```
gem install net-ssh
```

Here is a code snippet that processes the SSH authenication and then connects to the IP address of whatever remote host you choose.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
HOST = '192.168.1.113'
USER = 'username'
PASS = 'password'

Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh|
result = ssh.exec!('ls')
puts result
end
```

After connecting to the remote host, the session should be "interactive", but this is not an equivalent of Expect's Interact as far as I'm concerned. Here's a couple links that cover Ruby's built-in TTY and PTY modules: https://piotrmurach.github.io/tty/
 http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html. You will have to do another `gem install` command on the Ruby terminal for TTY.

Comment: AFAICT, this would run `ls` on the remote host, but it wouldn't give me standard input or standard output on my local terminal. If true, then that doesn't really address the problem I'm trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment, so posting as an answer, as I do the same thing using sshpass utility (if you don't have you can easily install)

```
#!/bin/ksh
IP=yourIP
ping -c 1 $IP 
if [ $? -gt 0 ]
 then
 echo "$IP not reachable." 
 exit
else
 echo "$IP is reachable"
fi
sshpass -p "yourpassword" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@$IP
```

if you want to log the output of the session, you can pipe the output to a logfile using tee command like 
`sshpass -p "yourpassword" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@$IP | tee -a logfile.log`